# Workspace switcher shortcuts do not work anymore and new windows will be placed under launcher

Tags: unity, xorg, launcher

I have a dual monitor setup under Ubuntu 16.04.1. After I updated a few days ago, the workspace switcher buttons (Ctrl-Alt-Arrows Keys) do not work anymore and each time I open a new window, it gets placed under the launcher and the top menu (see screenshot), instead of a next to those. Also, if I click on any of the launcher icons that indicate an active window, the workspace does not change anymore to the workspace where this window is placed. It does bring up the window if I am already in the correct workspace, though.

I do not know if there is a way to find out which packages were changed between 09/28/2016 and 09/29/2016, but I suspect it has to do with those, since I never had that problem before.

Also, I am not sure if unity is the right package or xorg to report as the source of the problem.

P.S.: here is an image that shows the problem:

[image: screenshot]

Also I created a bug where all the apport information is attached: [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1629212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This typically happens when compiz plugins become un-set for whatever reason. To re-enable them you can use command line, but simplest way is via CompizConfig Settings Manager (not installed by default, so run `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`).

The example of what I have is in screenshots below. The `Desktop Wall` plugin is responsible for viewport (workspace) switching  , while `Place Windows` is responsible for placement. Make sure they are checked. **Note** that `Viewport Switcher` is unchecked , since it provides extra keybindings for switching, but the default functionality is actually provided by `Desktop Wall`, not by `Viewport Switcher` plugin

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oh man, thx a lot. I actually checked compiz settings, but I looked only at keyboard commands and the Ctrl-Alt-Left/Right... shortcuts where there. So I figured the problem would be sth else.
Turns out Place Windows and Desktop Wall were turned off.

Comment: @ChristianDomsch  That's a common problem , not the first time dealing with this :)  If ever Unity misbehaves just check what plugins are unchecked. Glad I could help !

Comment: I will do that the next time. Just for future reference, is there some overview over the default set of plugins that are enabled on a fresh install? Or even a revert back to default?

Comment: @ChristianDomsch I don't think there is. Simplest way is just to check from virtual machine or new installation.